# HTML link that appends a query string to the current URL

Tags: html, url, query-string

I have a simple form like this:

```
 <form>
      <input name="search">
      <button type="submit">Search...</button>
      Price: <a href="?filter=price&direction=asc">Low</a> | 
             <a href="?filter=price&direction=desc">High</a>
 </form>
```

Note that `input` with the name of `search` allows to search for a keyword, while `<a>` links work as filters. When you submit the form, the URL would be e.g. `localhost/products?search=smartphone`. With my server-side script, this would yield a page with all products that contain a word `smartphone` in their name.

Now say I am at `localhost?search=smartphone`. If I click on `Low`, it would yield

```
http://localhost/products?filter=price&direction=asc
    -> filter all products with price asc
```

However, what I am really intending to get is

```
http://localhost/products?search=smartphone&filter=price&direction=asc
    -> search for 'smartphone', and filter only those results by price asc
```

How can I get to combine `search` and `filter` (with its `asc` or `desc` direction)? On a side note, is this efficient in terms of searching/filtering? Should I change `<a>` to `<input>`? I have little experience with searching mechanisms, so any suggestion would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

use

```
onclick="form.submit();"


<form id="my_form">
  <input name="search">

  Price: <a href="?search="+ escape(document.forms.my_form.search.value)+"&filter=price&direction=asc" onclick="document.getElementById('my_form').submit(); return false;">Low</a> | 
         <a href="?search="+ escape(document.forms.my_form.search.value)+"&filter=price&direction=desc" onclick="document.getElementById('my_form').submit(); return false;">High</a>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It either gives me `http://localhost/products?search=some_value` or `http://localhost/products?filter=name&direction=asc`. It needs to have both `filter` and `search`

Comment: Updated my ans. Check now.